# Добавление класса is_open

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не получается по клику добавить класс `is_open` к `td`:

```
$("td").click(function () {
    this.addClass("is_open")
})
```

Comment: this между скобками надо так $(this).addClass(newclass)

Comment: Спасибо! понял.

Answer (score 0):

Довольно неожиданно, но в обработчик `jQuery` передаёт непосредственно DOM-объект, без своей обёртки.

Поэтому либо оберните объект `this` в обёртку (`$(this)`), либо добавьте класс ванильными средствами, которые в современных браузерах удобнее и быстрее (`this.classList.add('yourClassName')`).